# Undefined function json_decode()

Tags: 7, drush

When attempting to update a Drupal 7 site through the UI or Drush, I get `Error: Call to undefined function json_decode() in home/xxxxx/drush/includes/output.inc, line 403 , code: 255)`

The server is running PHP 7.3 with json enabled - I've verified this with phpinfo(). I'm at a loss here, and even if I apply updates by ftp, I still can't run database updates. Shared hosting without root access.

- PHP 7.3.13
- Drush 5.9
- Drupal 7.x

Comment: Doesn't the same happen in a local copy of the site? Does the same happen on the live server when you call `json_decode` in a completely unrelated bare PHP script? Then this probably has nothing to do with Drupal, but with the hosting.

Comment: I have not made a local copy of the site, however it does occur on the production and staging site on the same server. json_decode does work from a script called from the web root. I spent an hour with hosting support to be told it's not a server issue. The only common denominator is drush, since both sites use that same install. So I'll try reinstalling drush and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the culprit. A php symlink in the bin directory linking to an old version of php. I guess even though drush showed it was using version 7.3, those scripts used that symlink and was pulling in an older php version. Error is gone and I can finally update through drush.